# Collisions with the earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

The earth is traveling around the sun at around 65,000 mph. An asteroid or other large object is traveling around 35,000 mph. Depending on the direction of the impact, the object could strike head on at a combined speed as high as 95,000 mph, or coming from the other direction not even be able to "catch" the earth. If this is correct could an impact range from 95,000 mph down to almost 0? I've never heard this explained, in fact I have always heard that the speed of an impact stated at around 35,00 mph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How gently could a comet/asteroid/meteorite “hit” Earth?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162386/)

Comment: @JohnRennie It's ever so slightly broader than that question: this one's asking for an upper limit as well as a lower one.

Comment: Well, the upper limit would be relativistic if you include cosmic rays :-) .  Otherwise the point is that it's just about impossible for an object to avoid be slowed down due to atmospheric drag.

Comment: Just to note, Dan: "An asteroid or other large object is traveling around 35,000 mph" assumes a particular subset of orbits. The upper limit for objects in solar orbit is the solar escape velocity - a bit shy of 1.4 million mph. For objects coming from outside the solar system, theoretically any subliminal speed is possible. However, the objects that are relatively *likely* to hit Earth will, generally, be in a similar orbit to and thus a similar orbital speed as Earth.